# Converting String to Int using try/except in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm pretty stumped on how to convert a string into an int using the try/except function. Does anyone know a simple function on how to do this? I feel like I'm still a little hazy on string and ints. I'm pretty confident that ints are related to numbers. Strings...not so much.

Answer (score 137):

It is important to be specific about what exception you're trying to catch when using a try/except block.

```py
string = "abcd"
try:
    string_int = int(string)
    print(string_int)
except ValueError:
    # Handle the exception
    print('Please enter an integer')
```

Try/Excepts are powerful because if something can fail in a number of different ways, you can specify how you want the program to react in each fail case.

Comment: +1 for being specific. It's worth noting that the `ValueError` `Exception` instance will contain more information, *viz.* "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abcd'".

Comment: Just wanted to mention... if there's a chance the variable you are converting is `None`, then you'll want your except block to be `except (TypeError, ValueError):`

Answer (score 27):

Here it is:

```
s = "123"
try:
  i = int(s)
except ValueError as verr:
  pass # do job to handle: s does not contain anything convertible to int
except Exception as ex:
  pass # do job to handle: Exception occurred while converting to int
```

Comment: -1 for catching almost every possible exception instead of just `ValueError`.  You should only catch what you know how to deal with.

Comment: Catching more than you need is **very** bad practice.  Adjust your answer and I'll happily change my vote.

Comment: +1 This is just an example, so showing the pattern to catch a ValueError and also other kinds of exception is very didactic. It's very useful for example to parse an argument and set a default value if invalid or not defined.

Comment: I happen to work on a very large python code base that had thrown a ton of exceptions left and right. And  at one point there was no other way to deal with it but catching all - you do not know what new exception a member of a different team working in a different country added last week 10 layers below  your code.
Coming from c++ I would say exceptions in python are way overused.

Answer (score 13):

Firstly, [`try` / `except`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/try.html) are not *functions*, but *statements*.

To convert a string ([or any other type that can be converted](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__)) to an integer in Python, simply call the [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) built-in function. `int()` will `raise` a [`ValueError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError) if it fails and you should catch this specifically:

### In Python 2.*x*:

```
>>> for value in '12345', 67890, 3.14, 42L, 0b010101, 0xFE, 'Not convertible':
...     try:
...         print '%s as an int is %d' % (str(value), int(value))
...     except ValueError as ex:
...         print '"%s" cannot be converted to an int: %s' % (value, ex)
...
12345 as an int is 12345
67890 as an int is 67890
3.14 as an int is 3
42 as an int is 42
21 as an int is 21
254 as an int is 254
"Not convertible" cannot be converted to an int: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Not convertible'
```

### In Python 3.*x*

the syntax has changed slightly:

```
>>> for value in '12345', 67890, 3.14, 42, 0b010101, 0xFE, 'Not convertible':
...     try:
...         print('%s as an int is %d' % (str(value), int(value)))
...     except ValueError as ex:
...         print('"%s" cannot be converted to an int: %s' % (value, ex))
...
12345 as an int is 12345
67890 as an int is 67890
3.14 as an int is 3
42 as an int is 42
21 as an int is 21
254 as an int is 254
"Not convertible" cannot be converted to an int: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Not convertible'
```

Comment: Is `ValueError` the only expected exception ? - the docs do not specify this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

Comment: `int()` can also raise a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#int) does not tell much about the exceptions that `int()` can raise; however, when you use `int()`, it can raise essentially two exception: `TypeError`, if the value is not a number or a string (or bytes, or bytearray), and `ValueError` if the value does not really map to a number.

You should manage both, with something like this:

```py
try:
   int_value = int(value)
except (TypeError, ValueError):
    print('Not an integer')
```

Answer (score 3):

In many cases, we want to get an integer value from the user. Users may insert non-integer values that should be warned and they should be prompted to try again. The following snippet can be used to get an integer value from the user and continue prompting the user to insert an integer until they put a valid one.

```
def get_integer_value():
  user_value = input("Enter an integer: ")
  try:
    return int(user_value)
  except ValueError:
    print(f"{user_value} is not a valid integer. Please try again.")
    return get_integer_value()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(f"You have inserted: {get_integer_value()}")
```

**Output:**

```
Enter an integer: asd
asd is not a valid integer. Please try again.
Enter an integer: 32
You have inserted: 32
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
try : 
   string_integer = int(string)
except ValueError  :
   print("This string doesn't contain an integer")
```

Comment: The syntax of your except statement is wrong - it will never catch anything. Multiple exceptions are caught using `except (type1, type2):` syntax. And there is no point combining a specific error with the general base class `Exception`.