# Trying to append variable to list in a while loop without appending variable that ends the while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having problems. The code works, but I want it to work without appending the final input from user.
Not sure how to end the loop without putting the incorrect variable in the list at the end.
    Quizzes = []

```
#Create variable to start the counter in the while loop
QuizNumber = 1

#Create variable to start while loop
QuizValue = 0

#Create while loop that ends if the user types anything outside of 0 and 15
while int(QuizValue) >= 0 and int(QuizValue) <= 15:

    #Get user input for quiz values
    QuizValue = input("Quiz " +str(QuizNumber) + ":")



    #Make if statement to end while loop if user types anything not integer
    if int(QuizValue) >= 0 or int(QuizValue) <= 15:
        QuizValue = QuizValue

        #Append to list
        Quizzes.append(QuizValue)

    else:
        QuizValue = 999


    #Counter for quiz number
    QuizNumber = QuizNumber + 1
```

Comment: What is this line: QuizValue = QuizValue?

Comment: I guess I don't need that. The focus was more on QuizValue = 999 to end the loop. I deleted it and still got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Quizzes = Quizzes[:-1]` after the loop

This splices the list and gives you a new list which has all except the last item

Comment: `Quizzes.pop()` would probably be a little more preferable because it's more performant (doesn't make a whole new list).

Answer (score 0):

A common Python idiom is to use `while 1:` to begin an "infinite" loop, but then to have a `break` statement in the middle of the loop when a certain condition is met.  This takes the place of the `do ... until` form found in other languages.  So:

```
while 1:  # an "infinite" loop
    QuizValue = input("Quiz " +str(QuizNumber) + ":")
    # Do something if QuizValue is between 0 and 15
    if 0 <= int(QuizValue) <= 15:
        Quizzes.append(QuizValue)
    else:
        break
```

By the way, in your code, this:

```
if int(QuizValue) >= 0 or int(QuizValue) <= 15:
```

...will always be true.  Every single number is either greater than zero or less than 15.

Answer (score 0):

#### pop

You could use `pop` to remove the last item:

```
QuizNumber = 1
QuizValue = 0
while 0 <= int(QuizValue) <= 15:
    QuizValue = input("Quiz " +str(QuizNumber) + ":")
    Quizzes.append(QuizValue)
    QuizNumber = QuizNumber + 1
Quizzes.pop()
```

That way you wouldn't need an `if` statement at all.

Also note that I rewrote that `0 <= x and x <= 15` conditional to `0 <= x <= 15` which is the same thing in Python.

#### infinite loop

If you'd like an `if` statement, you could actually loop infinitely with `while True` and then use `break`.  This way you don't need to write the same conditional check twice:

```
QuizNumber = 1
QuizValue = 0
while True:
    QuizValue = input("Quiz " +str(QuizNumber) + ":")
    if not (0 <= int(QuizValue) <= 15):
        break
    Quizzes.append(QuizValue)
    QuizNumber = QuizNumber + 1
```

Again note that `x < 0 or x > 15` is the same as `not (0 <= x <= 15)`

#### A couple unrelated code suggestions

You might want to try using the `format` method on strings instead of using string concatenation.  This will allow you to turn:

```
    quiz_value = input("Quiz " +str(quiz_number) + ":")
```

Into:

```
    quiz_value = input("Quiz {n}:".format(n=quiz_number))
```

You also may want to use `underscore_case` in your variable names instead of `CamelCase` (underscore case is more idiomatic in Python).

```
quiz_number = 1
quiz_value = 0
while 0 <= int(quiz_value) <= 15:
    quiz_value = input("Quiz {n}:".format(n=quiz_number))
    quizzes.append(quiz_value)
    quiz_number = quiz_number + 1
quizzes.pop()
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know any way to end the loop by pressing enter? Right now it's giving me "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ' "

Comment: When you convert any arbitrary string to an integer, it may fail by raising an exception. You're going to want to catch that exception.

In your case I would remove the `int(quiz_value)` and instead put your `input()` call in an `int()` call like so: `quiz_value = int(input("Quiz {n}:".format(n=quiz_number)))`.

Then you'll just need to wrap that line in a try-except to handle the exception (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8075959/98187).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Always use try, except clause when dealing with unexpected input from user.
Following code uses a boolean Flag to break while loop and avoids else condition.

```
QuizNumber = 1
QuizValue = 0
Quizzes = []
flag = True

while flag:
    try:
        QuizValue = input("Quiz " +str(QuizNumber) + ":")
        flag = False
        if str(QuizValue).isdigit():
            if int(QuizValue) >= 0 and int(QuizValue) <= 15:
                Quizzes.append(QuizValue)
                QuizNumber = QuizNumber + 1
                flag = True
    except Exception as e:
        flag = False
```