# Variable not being recognized as integer in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, int

Here is my code:

```
print "How many frames do you want?"
f = raw_input()
print f
frames = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

if f > 0:
    frames = frames[:f]
    print frames
```

Then when I run it (my input was 2), I get this error where the variable f is not being recognized as an int, even though when I print it, my input printed an int (2).

Here's the error message: 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "melissa.py", line 11, in 
            frames = frames[:f]
    TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an    **index** method...

So, f is 2, but I can't use it to slice the string??

Comment: Use `f = int(raw_input())`. You're getting the input as `str` instead of `int`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The official python documentation clearly says that `raw_input` returns a string. Before asking here, you should check the documentation. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you did not convert the input into an integer. Therefore, Python does not recognize it as an integer.

[`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) will take an input from stdin and spit out a string. Python does not automatically check if the string is an integer. However, there is a method for that (`isdigit()`).

So what you need to do is to convert it into an integer using the `int()` converter before you continue:

```
f = int(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 0):

The `raw_input()` function returns a string regardless of what you type in.

To turn that into an actual integer, you could use something like:

```
f = int(raw_input())
```

However, be aware that is not going to go well unless you actually enter an integer. You should really catch exceptions for both a failed `raw_input()` and a failed `int()`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075877/converting-string-to-int-using-try-except-in-python) for how to do the latter, you can use a similar method to catch `EOFError` (and others if need be) for the former.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `raw_input` to `input`.`raw_input` takes it as a string whereas `input` takes it as a integer.
Here is the code:

```
 print "How many frames do you want?"
    f = input()
    print f
    frames = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

    if f > 0:
        frames = frames[:f]
        print frames
```

Comment: This seems an incredibly bad idea since `input()` is effectively `eval(raw_input())` - you really don't want to be evaluating user entered strings.

Comment: @paxdiablo, okay, thanks for the information :).