# Confusion with valueError vs ValueType try/exception

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, value-type

I have a follow up question to a post I saw on converting a str() input to a int() type. Based on the definitions of valueError and valueType I would expect the valueType exception to have been used however, it doesn't work (when i tried it). ValueError works but I'm not sure why, isn't int('some string') an example of a wrong type?

Link to original post i'm referring to: [Converting String to Int using try/except in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075877/converting-string-to-int-using-try-except-in-python)

Comment: There's no `ValueType` exception in python standard library as far as I know. Where did you see that?

Comment: are you refering to `NoneType` by saying `ValueType` ?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> class int(x, base=10) Return an integer object constructed from a
>   number or string x, or return 0 if no arguments are given. If x is a
>   number, return x.**int**(). For floating point numbers, this truncates
>   towards zero.
>
> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string,
>   bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix
>   base. Optionally, the literal can be preceded by + or - (with no space
>   in between) and surrounded by whitespace. A base-n literal consists of
>   the digits 0 to n-1, with a to z (or A to Z) having values 10 to 35.
>   The default base is 10. The allowed values are 0 and 2–36. Base-2, -8,
>   and -16 literals can be optionally prefixed with 0b/0B, 0o/0O, or
>   0x/0X, as with integer literals in code. Base 0 means to interpret
>   exactly as a code literal, so that the actual base is 2, 8, 10, or 16,
>   and so that int('010', 0) is not legal, while int('010') is, as well
>   as int('010', 8).

When you call the int() function on a string it will try to convert it to the specified base in the arguments (by default base-10) by iterating over the string and converting the string object over to an int object in the desired base. If it reaches a point where the conversion can not be made due to illegal syntax , it will raise a ValueError so terminate the program early. If for some reason you want to go forward you can but a try: except block in the code to catch the exception.

From the Docs:

> exception ValueError Raised when a built-in operation or function
>   receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate
>   value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception
>   such as IndexError.