# How to give out an Error instead of the system error

Tags: python, string, error-handling, numbers, int

Hey there so i have my number guesser in python3.But i want to give out an Error if the User types letters instead of numbers.When i type a letter it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nummerlol.py", line 14, in <module>
    guess = int(guess)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:"
```

Is there a way to change this error? thx

```
import time
import random 
from secrets import randbelow
guesscount = 0
print("Hey whats your name")
name = input()
number = randbelow(20)
print("The Number is between 1 & 20")
while guesscount < 6:
    print("Guess.")
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)
    guesscount = guesscount + 1
    if guess < number:
        print("My Number is bigger")
    if guess > number:
        print("My Number is lower")
    if guess == number:
        break
if guess == number :
guesscount = str(guesscount)
print("Nice",name ,".")
print("You needed" ,guesscount ,"Tries")
if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print("Bruh,My Number was" ,number)`
```

Comment: Do you want to change the ErrorType `ValueError` or the error message

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: What does `give out an Error` mean.  You need to describe what you want to happen when the user gives an invalid response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a try-except loop.  With `continue` (as below) the user can keep guessing.  You could also put your own exception in place of the `print` and `continue` if you want the script to break with a more informative message.

```
import time
import random 
from secrets import randbelow
guesscount = 0
print("Hey whats your name")
name = input()
number = randbelow(20)
print("The Number is between 1 & 20")
while guesscount < 6:
    print("Guess.")
    guess = input()
    try:
        guess = int(guess)
    except:
        print("That is not a number")
        continue
    guesscount = guesscount + 1
    if guess < number:
        print("My Number is bigger")
    if guess > number:
        print("My Number is lower")
    if guess == number:
        break
if guess == number :
    guesscount = str(guesscount)
print("Nice",name ,".")
print("You needed" ,guesscount ,"Tries")
if guess != number:
    number = str(number)
    print("Bruh,My Number was" ,number)
```

Comment: thx.worked for me :D

Answer (score 0):

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075877/converting-string-to-int-using-try-except-in-python) to yours already exists, but I'll answer your question anyway.

As you already know, the reason you're getting a traceback response is because you're trying to convert a non-integer into an integer when you call `int(guess)`. You can catch this exception using a try/except block. For example, you could replace the offending line of code with the following:

```
while True:
  try:
    guess = int(guess)
    break
  except ValueError:
    print("You must enter a valid number.")
```

This code will cause the program to require input from the user until that input is valid. Have a look at this Python3 [handling errors and exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: If you identified this question as a duplicate then you shouldn't even answer - either vote to close the question or if you can't yet post a comment linking to the duplicate.