# How can I add an exit for users with int inputs

Tags: python

I need users to be able to type x to exit if they get a question wrong.

I've tried changing the input to a string and then if the answer isn't x then convert the string to an integer with int(user_ans) and even making another value and with ans_string == int(user_ans).  Is there any way to add a break to the end if they type x?

```
if level == 1:
    solution = number_one + number_two
    print("What is", number_one, "plus", number_two)
    user_ans = int(input())

if user_ans == solution:
    print("Correct")
    number_one = random.randrange(1,10)
    number_two = random.randrange(1,10)
    rounds = rounds + 1
else:
    print("Try again")
```

I expect the program to still function but also be for the user to quit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `try` block to see whether the input is a number and change what you do. Something like this:

```
is_int = false
user_ans = input()

try: 
  ans_int = int(user_ans)
  is_int = true
except:
  is_int = false

if is_int:
  # Do what you need with the integer
  if ans_int == 1:
    solution = number_one + number_two
    print("What is", number_one, "plus", number_two)
    user_ans = int(input())
elif user_ans == solution:
  print("Correct")
  number_one = random.randrange(1,10)
  number_two = random.randrange(1,10)
  rounds = rounds + 1
elif user_ans == "x":
  # Do what you need to do if it is an "x"
else:
   print("Try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the user's input into a variable, like with `inStr = input('Enter input: ')`. Then, you can check it to see if it's `'x'`; if it is, you can use `sys.exit()` (or some other function), and if it's not, you can then cast it to a number and use it. `inNum = int(inStr)`

By checking the variable first and *then* casting it, you don't have to worry about what happens if your code tries to run `int('x')`.

If you really want to cast your input to `int` right away, though, [you can use `try` and `except` to catch a `ValueError`,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8075959/7431860) which is what `int()` will throw if you give it a non-number input. This won't specifically check for `'x'` - just for some invalid input.