# In Python queries whether an input is an int or a str

Tags: python

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
import os

if Name == "Germany" or Name == "Italy" or Name == "Poland": 
        Height = int(input("How high should the image be? Maximum is 4608 pixels."))
        if Height < 1:
            print(Fore.RED + "This is not a valid height!")
            exit()
        elif height > 0:
            Width = int(Height * (16 / 9))
```

The following problem:

So far the program can already determine if the input is below 1, which would be an invalid height for an image. But how do I do that if I want to prevent that when a letter or something else is entered that such an ugly error message appears and the program instead

```
print(Fore.RED + "This is not a valid height!")
exit()
```

executes

If some more code is needed to understand the context, please let me know

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not in English.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075877/converting-string-to-int-using-try-except-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use **Exception**, except `ValueError` and `TypeError`

**Code Syntax**

```
try:
    Height = int(input("How high should the image be? Maximum is 4608 pixels."))
        if Height < 1:
            print(Fore.RED + "This is not a valid height!")
            exit()
        elif height > 0:
            Width = int(Height * (16 / 9))
except (TypeError, ValueError):
    print(Fore.RED + "This is not a valid height!")
    exit()
```