# Is there a way to make an integer input output a certain thing when a sting or float is inputted?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Here is my code:**

```
x = 1
while x == 1:
  fav_number = int(input("Guess my favorite number: "))
  print()
  if fav_number == 8:
    print("Gongrats, you guessed it!")
    x = 2
  else:
    print("Nope, try again!")
    print()
```

**In this example, I want it to also say "Nope, try again!" when the user inputs in a float or a string without crashing the program.**

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075877/converting-string-to-int-using-try-except-in-python/8075959 covers what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    try: #Use the try/except block to raise exception if value is not integer
        fav_number = int(input("Guess my favorite number: "))
        print()
    except ValueError: # if value is anything but integer, exception is raised
        print("Invalid entry. Try again.")
    else:
        if fav_number == 8:
            print("Gongrats, you guessed it!")
            break #code ends when number is guessed
        else:
            print("Nope, try again!")
```

To make it more interesting, you can add a predefined number of attempts. If attempts are exhausted, code stops:

```
attempts = 5
while attempts > 0:
    attempts -= 1
    try: #Use the try/except block to raise exception if value is not integer
        fav_number = int(input("Guess my favorite number: "))
        print()
    except ValueError: # if value is anything but integer, exception is raised
        print("Invalid entry. Try again.")
    else:
        if attempts > 0:
            if fav_number == 8:
                print("Gongrats, you guessed it!")
                break #code ends when number is guessed
            else:
                print("Nope, try again!")
                print(f"You have {attempts} left")
        else:
            print("You have exhausted your attempts.")
```

Comment: If you find the answer satisfactory, please check it as "Accept Answer". Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can, use `eval` in python for the string would convert int to int and float to float without exception. Check the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

So basically you can change the `int` to `eval`:

```py
x = 1
while x == 1:
  fav_number = eval(input("Guess my favorite number: "))
  print()
  if fav_number == 8:
    print("Gongrats, you guessed it!")
    x = 2
  else:
    print("Nope, try again!")
    print()
```