# Python - How do i make this code work if inserted value is float or negative?

Tags: python

if the user inputed -777 or 77.1 how do i make the program work instead of saying inputed number is a string?

main file

```
from  helper import *

def main():
#  menu 
    user_selection = ""
    while user_selection != "x":
        print("a - Input something")
        print("x - exit")
        # get the user selection
        user_selection = input("select an option: ")
        print("The user select: "+user_selection)
        # implement the user selection
        if user_selection == "a":
            input_analyst()
            break
       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

helper file

```
from os.path import exists
from tracemalloc import stop


# this was done purely by hand and google was never used so it might not be size-effective
def input_analyst():

    user_input = input("your input: ")
    # Return True if the string is a numeric string, False otherwise.
    if user_input.isnumeric():
        print("Entered user_input is Integer:", user_input)
        num = int(user_input)  # if its an int set num as the inputed value

    else:
        # if the inputed data is a string print so and stop the function
        print("Entered user_input is a string")
        return

    if user_input.isnumeric():  # if its a int display it's lengh
        print("The int lengh is: ", len(user_input))

    if (num % 2) == 0:  # check if the number is even or odd
        print("{} is an Even number".format(num))
    else:
        print("{} is an Odd number".format(num))

    if num % 7 == 0:  # check if the number is dividable by 7 without a remainder or not and prints how much it would actually be if Divided by 7
        number1 = num
        number2 = 7
        result = number1/number2
        print("{} Dividable by 7 without a remainder".format(num))
        print("{} Dividable by 7 =: {} ".format(num, result))

    else:
        number1 = num
        number2 = 7
        result = number1/number2
        print("{} Isn't dividable by 7 without a remainder".format(num))
        print("{} Divided by 7 =: {} ".format(num, result))
```

if the user inputed -777 or 77.1 how do i make the program work instead of saying inputed number is a string?

Comment: You should convert it to number

Comment: You're checking for divisibility by 2 and 7. Do you want to keep doing that once your program accepts float inputs? It really only makes sense for integers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075877/converting-string-to-int-using-try-except-in-python Try to use something like that, to directly convert the input to integer with error handling if it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a conversion to float together with try / except like:

```
try:
    num = int(float(user_input))
    print("Entered user input is Integer:", user_input)

except ValueError:
    print("Entered user_input is a string")
    return
```

In that case you would also accept things like "-77.5" as an integer (-77).
If you don't want that you could add a check:

```
int(float(user_input)) == float(user_input)
```

Now one might say that the intermediate conversion to float is not necessary, but from your question it seems like you also want to accept things like `77.0` as intergers.

Answer (score -1):

You would do this at the `input()` level in what you have called the helper file.

So something like this would work:

```py
user_input = input("your input: ")

# first convert to an int
user_input = int(user_input)

if user_input <0:
    # some logic
    print('warning, negative number, convert to positive')
    user_input = -user_input

print(user_input)
```